# Error's (PK's and FK's tried in the correct order)

Tags: php, sql, html

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mowanj1_in605`.`sportEvent`, CONSTRAINT `sportEvent_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`eventID`) REFERENCES `event` (`eventID`))' in /home/mowanj1/public_html/Web2/Assignment1/createAthlete.html.php on line 222
>
> ( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mowanj1_in605`.`sportEvent`, CONSTRAINT `sportEvent_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`eventID`) REFERENCES `event` (`eventID`)) in /home/mowanj1/public_html/Web2/Assignment1/createAthlete.html.php on line 222

```
$createQuery = "CREATE TABLE sportEventMedal 
sportEventMedalID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, sportEventID INT, medalID INT, 
PRIMARY KEY (sportEventMedalID), FOREIGN KEY (sportEventID) REFERENCES sportEvent(sportEventID), FOREIGN KEY (medalID) REFERENCES medal(medalID) 
$pdo->exec($createQuery);
while (! feof($file)) {
    $temp = fgetcsv($file);
    $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO sportEvent(eventID, sportID) VALUES('$temp[0]','$temp[1]')";
    $pdo->exec($insertQuery);
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: $createQuery = "CREATE TABLE sportEventMedal

Comment: sportEventMedalID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            sportEventID INT,
            medalID INT,

Comment: PRIMARY KEY (sportEventMedalID),
            FOREIGN KEY (sportEventID) REFERENCES sportEvent(sportEventID),
            FOREIGN KEY (medalID) REFERENCES medal(medalID)

Comment: $pdo->exec($createQuery);

Comment: while (! feof($file))
    {
        $temp = fgetcsv($file);
        $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO sportEvent(eventID, sportID)
        VALUES('$temp[0]','$temp[1]')";

        $pdo->exec($insertQuery);

    }
    fclose($file);

Comment: Please don't post random code snippets as comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Please follow the http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve instructions to improve your post

Answer (score 0):

You should load `event` and `sport` before loading `sportEvent`. If you're already doing that correctly, then your csv file contains inconsistent data - rows that contain invalid `eventID` values. One option is to ignore those rows, you can query to see if the event exists before trying to insert or you can just ignore the error. Another option is to create an event for the missing ID and then to retry the insert into `sportEvent`. The easiest and worst option is to remove the foreign key constraint, that'll allow you to insert invalid data into your database and ignore the problem for now.